# Be sure that only browsers without addons/extensions access my webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an admin panel, I would like to permit only browsers without any extension/addon.

I tried setting stringent csp policy

```
content-security-policy: 
    script-src 'nonce-xxx' 'strict-dynamic' https: 'unsafe-inline'; 
    object-src 'none'; 
    base-uri 'self'; 
    block-all-mixed-content;
```

but it seems that Chrome addons can bypass it.

Comment: There's no solution generally. Extensions use a different mechanism (content scripts) which the web page can't control but there are various bugs in browsers that you can utilize e.g. https://bugzil.la/1411641. Note that extensions can override any header the page sets, but in Chrome they can't override `<meta>` tag for CSP in your html, which is possible in Firefox.

Comment: You should not include script-src  "https:" and "'unsafe-inline'" if you want to make it stringent. That will include scripts from any source on https and any inline script.

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug on modern browsers they are inactive, they work only on old browser as a backward compatibility layer, you can test it with [CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/)